# The display of some images through the readfile does not work

Tags: php, readfile, getimagesize

I have this simple function that I use to display images on a website (due to mixed content) but it doesn't work for this particular one. How to view it?

Code:

```
<?php
$remoteImage = "http://data.rcm-pelikan.cz/products2/KAV0152&5/b_0_779bc.jpg";
$imginfo = getimagesize($remoteImage);
header("Content-type: ".$imginfo['mime']);
readfile($remoteImage);
```

Edit:
Solution:

```
$remoteImage = "http://data.rcm-pelikan.cz/products2/KAV0152&5/b_0_779bc.jpg";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $remoteImage);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
$rescode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$contentType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
curl_close($ch) ;

header("Content-Type: $contentType");
echo $res;
```

Comment: There's nothing unusual about that image.  Have you looked at the response you're sending, using `wget` or `curl`?  What you're doing is wasteful, because you're downloading the file twice.  There are ways around that.

Comment: Wow i tried curl again and it works. thanks a lot. Code pasted above

Comment: Well, I'm glad it worked, but that's not really what I meant.  What I meant was using the `curl` command line to fetch YOUR web page and see what you were actually sending.

Comment: I do not understand now. Can you please give an example?

Comment: I'm not sure it's worth your trouble, if you have a solution.  Your PHP file is itself a web page, right?  You are probably looking at it in a browser, but you can use the `curl` command line tool to fetch the page and look at the contents.